# Matching phone numbers, regex

Tags: python, regex

I've phone numbers in this format:

```
 some_text   phone_number some_text
 some_text   (888) 501-7526 some_text
```

Which is a more pythonic way way to search for the phone numbers

```
(\(\d\d\d\) \d\d\d-\d\d\d\d)

(\([0-9]+\) [0-9]+-[0-9]+)
```

or there is a simpler expresion to do this?

Comment: Note that you can use `\d+`, which is better than `[0-9]+`, but in any case your two regexes are not equivalent. `\d\d\d` will match 502 and 918 but not 1 or 2412, while `\d+` or `[0-9]+` would match any of those numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
(\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4})
```

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> {m}
>
> Specifies that exactly m copies of the previous RE should be
>   matched; fewer matches cause the entire RE not to match. For example,
>   a{6} will match exactly six 'a' characters, but not five.

`(\(\d\d\d\) \d\d\d-\d\d\d\d)` would also work, but, as you said in your question, is rather repetitive. Your other suggested pattern, `(\([0-9]+\) [0-9]+-[0-9]+)`, gives false positives on input such as `(1) 2-3`.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Using `(\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}-\d{4})`

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "some_text   (888) 501-7526 some_text"
>>> pat = re.compile(r'(\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}-\d{4})')
>>> pat.search(s).group() 
'(888) 501-7526'
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/iQ9bF2/2)

Explanation:

- `(\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}-\d{4})/`

  - 1st Capturing group `(\(\d{3}\)\s*\d{3}-\d{4})`

    - `\(` matches the character `(` literally
    - `\d{3}` match a digit `[0-9]`

      - Quantifier: `{3}` Exactly 3 times
    - `\)` matches the character `)` literally
    - `\s*` match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`

      - Quantifier: `*` Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    - `\d{3}` match a digit [0-9]
      Quantifier: `{3}` Exactly 3 times
    - `-` matches the character - literally
    - `\d{4}` match a digit [0-9]
      Quantifier: `{4}` Exactly 4 times

Comment: There is an advantage over using: "re.findall('(\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4})'s)[0]"  ?

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez  `re.search` look for the first match where `re.findall` return a list.

Comment: Why are you using .group(1) and not .group(0)?

Comment: It should be `group(0)`  or simply `group()`  since what you want is the entire matching string. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second one would be the more pythonic way. The one above isn't that easy to read, but regular expressions aren't that intuitive at all.

`(\([0-9]+\) [0-9]+-[0-9]+)` will do it, if the lenght of the phone number is not specified. If the length is always the same, you can use `(\([0-9]{3}\) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})` or `(\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4})`.

Comment: If OP doesn't need to match other Unicode digits, `[0-9]` is also faster than `\d`.